# Getting "ErrorAccessDenied" while trying to query for a user's office365 profile photo using Microsoft Graph API v1.0

Tags: c#, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an "ErrorAccessDenied" when attempting to get user photos with the Microsoft Graph API v1.0.

I can get a user's information by using

```
var user = graphClient.Users["userprincipalname"].Request().GetAsync();
```

And I am also able to use

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userprincipalname/photo/$value"
```

In Microsoft's graph explorer to get a user's photo

However when I try to use

```
var user = graphClient.Users["userprincipalname"].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

I get

```
{Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again. Inner error
}
```

But I'm pretty sure my credentials are correct as I could get all the other information regarding the user.
My app is registered in Azure Portal and uses the v1.0 endpoint if that helps.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is you application authenticating using the same creds that you use when testing in the graph explorer?

Comment: What permissions is you app asking for when requesting the OAuth token?

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT in the Azure portal, I set the application's permissions for User.ReadBasic.All, Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All for both application permission and delegate permission

Comment: @yfan183 Thanks for the info.  Can you please provide a sample response including header that provides the request ID?

Comment: Also please make sure that the user has consented the app after you added the permissions.

Comment: @Yina-MSFT i think that might be where the problem is, the user was consented before the addition of the new permissions. But how do I re-consent the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If application permissions were updated after the user consented, a re-consent is needed. To force showing consent dialog to user, include prompt=consent query parameter to /authorize request. Example:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?prompt=consent`

Comment: I'm not sure where to add it as I used the built-in `Configure Azure AD Authentication` function from Visual Studio to authorize the users